# name 'movies' is not defined, print the list inside the function

Tags: python

how can i print Movies list
do i have to put the list outside the function?
I have tried to put Movie variable outside the function and the movie list got printed, do i have to put it outside the function?

```
def menu():
    user_input = input('inter "a" to add a movie, "i" to show a movie, "f" to find a movie, "q" to stop  ')
    while user_input != 'q':
        if user_input == 'a':
            add_movie()
        elif user_input == 'i':
            show_movie()
        elif user_input == 'f':
            find_movie()
        else:
            print('unknown command')
        user_input = input('inter "a" to add a movie, "i" to show a movie, "f" to find a movie, "q" to stop  ')


def add_movie():
    movies = [] `if i moved this variable out the function it get printed`
    name = input('what is movie name? ')
    date = int(input('date of movie? '))
    dirctor = input('directer name? ')

    movies.append({
        'name': name,
        'data': date,
        'dirctor': dirctor
    })


menu()
print(movies)
```

enter code here

Comment: You can also define it in menu(), then pass it to add_movie, and return it, and then return it from menu()

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does need to be outside the function. This has to do with scope. Any variables created inside a code block will only be accessible from inside that block. A function is a type of code block, so the `movies = []` that you have inside of `add_movie()` will be deleted as soon as you leave the function. If however, you place the declaration `movies = []` outside the function, then the values will not be deleted when the function leaves, which is the behaviour I assume you want.

Another option is to return the value of `movies` from `add_movie()` and also from `menu()`

Answer (score 0):

A variable inside of a function cannot be accessed outside of that function, unless you return it.

This is part of what is called scope, which is the places in code you can and can't access a variable.

For your situation you have a few options, here is what I see to be the easiest:

*I took out some of your lines to get it to compile as I don't have your other functions*

```
def menu():
    user_input = input('inter "a" to add a movie, "i" to show a movie, "f" to find a movie, "q" to stop  ')
    while user_input != 'q':
        if user_input == 'a':
            movies = add_movie()    # Change made here
        else:
            print('unknown command')
        user_input = input('inter "a" to add a movie, "i" to show a movie, "f" to find a movie, "q" to stop  ')
    return movies    #Change made here


def add_movie():
    movies = []
    name = input('what is movie name? ')
    date = int(input('date of movie? '))
    dirctor = input('directer name? ')
    movies.append({'name': name, 'data': date, 'dirctor': dirctor})
    return movies    # Change made here


movies = menu()    # Change made here
print(movies)
```